# build regex with some conditionals

Tags: regex

I don't know how to build regex with some conditional statement, namely: I have to search in the text the following:

```
[infdca]{0,4}r[i][nf]
```

which returns some words, ok. 
But, I wanna restrict `[i]` into the statement sth like this:

```
[infdca]{0,4}r(?[i][nf])
```

I mean, if `[i]` exists then `[nf]` add to regex, otherwise not.
This above does return anyting, or when I change something, it returns, for example, a word `firn` which is not correct, because group `[nf]` not follows directly letter `r`. There must be `[i]` first or nothing behind `r`.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Some more sample inputs would help.

Comment: just make `([i][nf])?` this makes the whole group optional...but as a group

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that the text ends with `i[nf]` or not, you can move the `?`:

```
[infdca]{0,4}r(i[nf])?
```

(You may have to put `\` before the `(`, `)`, or `?` depending on your regex flavour.)

Answer (score 0):

### Implement Regex Optional Group

if you want `[nf]` to only be part if `[i]` then you need to make a group and make said group optional.

```
[infdca]{0,4}r(?([i][nf])?)
```

this makes `([i][nf])?` all optional...so `[nf]` only is searched if the whole group exists...but it doesn't have to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match words, you need word boundaries there - `\b` or something like that. That's it. (Or `^` and `$` if matching a list of words.)